# Is the set of all singular $2\times2$ matrices a subspace of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the set of all singular $2\times2$ matrices a subspace of $R^3$?

I guess that what must be proven is whether the addition of two singular $2\times2$ remains singular or could otherwise be nonsingular. In the case of scalar multiplication it must hold: any singular matrix A, has $det(A)=0$, then $det(\alpha A)=\alpha(ad-cb)=0$ since $\alpha$ would just be a common factor and the equality will remain true.

Comment: Can you write the identity matrix as a sum of singular matrices?

Comment: no, you are right, and one case is enough, thanks.

Comment: @pjs36 i added the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$, the set of $2\times 2$ singular matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}$, is not a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4$, then it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^3$. the vector space $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$ of all $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^4$. However, $S_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4$. For example, take $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{F}$, and look at $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}\quad\hbox{and}\quad \pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}\ $. They're both singular, but their sum is not. So $S_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$ isn't a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4\implies S_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$ isn't a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is the set of all singular matrices that $\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$

$C1:A+B \in S$

$\begin{bmatrix}
\ a_1 \ a_2 \\ a_3 \ a_4   
\end{bmatrix} 
$ $+$ $\begin{bmatrix}
\ b_1 \ b_2 \\ b_3 \ b_4   
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\ a_1 + b_1 \ a_2 + b_2 \\ a_3 + b_3 \ a_4 + b_4
\end{bmatrix}$

$det(A)=0$ implies that $a_1a_4=a_3a_2$

$det(B)=0$ implies that $b_1b_4=b_3b_2$

then:

$det(A+B) = (a_1+b_1)(a_4+b_4)-(a_3+b_3)(a_2+b_2)
\\det(A+B) = (a_1a_4 + a_1b_4 + b_1a_4 + b_1b_4) - (a_3a_2+a_3b_2+b_3a_2+b_3b_2)$

now, since $a_1a_4=a_3a_2$ and $b_1b_4=b_3b_2$

$det(A+B) = a_1b_4 + b_1a_4 - a_3b_2 - b_3a_2$ which could not be equal to zero and therefore $A+B$ may not b singular and $A+B \notin S$

Comment: You're making it too complicated: just take $A=(1,0,0,0)$ and $B=(0,0,0,1)$, $|A|=|B|=0\neq 1=|I|=|A+B|$ .

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD you are right and it does the trick since you are proving that an element resulting of the sum of two elements in the set could not belong to the set, therefore establishing that it is not a subset. but i just wanted to prove the general case